# Drawing pixels inside a grid in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a paint program which shows a zoomed in version of the image you are editing and I have the interpolation mode set to "nearest neighbor". Also, I have a pixel grid which is drawn on there and the grid is perfectly over each place that there is a pixel on the image. So it shows you the accurate amount of pixels.
I added a brush to draw on the picturebox with but I want the brush to draw exactly on the squares like in other drawing programs with pixel grid views. So as long as the mouse pointer is within that pixel square, it will only fill the inside of that pixel square that it is in. Here are the codes:
(my picturebox is named canvaseditor.)

the code that generates the pixel grid:

```
Private Sub canvaseditor_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles canvaseditor.Paint
        If Not bmpNew Is Nothing Then
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpNew, 0, 0)
        End If

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim pn As New Pen(Color.DimGray) '~~~ color of the lines

        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer

        Dim intSpacing As Integer = 8  '~~~ spacing between adjacent lines

        '~~~ Draw the horizontal lines
        x = canvaseditor.Width
        For y = 0 To canvaseditor.Height Step intSpacing
            g.DrawLine(pn, New Point(0, y), New Point(x, y))
        Next

        '~~~ Draw the vertical lines
        y = canvaseditor.Height
        For x = 0 To canvaseditor.Width Step intSpacing
            g.DrawLine(pn, New Point(x, 0), New Point(x, y))
        Next
    End Sub
```

Here is the interpolation code:
(TL14 is just one of the many pictureboxes which contain the original image that will be edited in canvaseditor and the scalefactor is just a variable integer set to 1)

```
If TL14.Image Is Nothing Then
        Else
            canvaseditor.Image = Nothing
            canvaseditor.Image = TL14.Image
            canvaseditor.Width = TL14.Width * 8 + 1
            canvaseditor.Height = TL14.Height * 8 + 1
            'load and draw the image(s) once
            BackgroundImage1 = New Bitmap(TL14.Image)
            bmpNew = New Bitmap(canvaseditor.Width * scaleFactor, canvaseditor.Height * scaleFactor)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew)
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
                g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
                g.DrawImage(BackgroundImage1, 0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height)
            End Using
            canvaseditor.Focus()
            GroupBox13.Focus()
        End If
```

This allows me to click on the original TL14 picturebox and load the image into the canvaseditor picturebox, scales it up to larger size, draws a pixelgrid, and takes away the antialiasing when images are stretched. so you get this in the end:

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hsoa63rnv2frk8/pixeledged.png?dl=0)

[This is what it does when I draw on it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3zbv2iffjgc8tt/sad.png?dl=0)

But when I draw on it, it doesnt line up exactly inside the squares. It just draws where my mouse is so how do I restrict that?

Comment: You don't show your mouse-drawing code, clearly you are doing it wrong.  Simple way is to map the mouse position back to the pixel, call SetPixel and repaint the grid.

Comment: You're multiplying by 8 to get a zoomed in size.  How can you go backwards from the mouse position and determine the original pixel position?...